How to set the size of the image in IEEE format
The size of the image does not adjust according to the document, following the IEEE format.
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centerline{\includegraphics[width=100px]{first.png}}
\caption{caption}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}


Welcome to TeX SE. Could you expand your code to make it compilable? It should start with \documentclass and end with \end{document}.

Why are you using px here? And what exactly do you mean by  image does not adjust according to the document?

why is this tagged biblatex or overleaf?

Nobody really knows why px has been introduced in pdftex, because PDF has nothing to do with HTML, where px units may make sense.
What you want is possibly \columnwidth or a fraction thereof.
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\columnwidth]{first.png}}
\caption{caption}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}

Use any factor (at most 1) instead of 0.9.
By the way, don't use \centerline if you don't really know what it does, because its effects might be very surprising.

You can also use width=\textwidth or scale=1.0 to adjust the size.

@mab0189 IEEE papers use two-column format. And scale=1 does nothing at all to the size: you'd get the image at its natural size.

I know that but even in a two-column format you can use pictures that span above both columns. The one was just an example value obviously.

@mab0189 In that case one has to use figure*, not figure.
